# Interesting examples of discrete stochastic games

Tags: game-theory, environment, markov-decision-process, benchmarks

[SGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_game) are a generalization of [MDPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) to multiple agents. Like this [previous question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/benchmarks-for-reinforcement-learning-in-discrete-mdps) on MDPs, are there any interesting examples of zero-sum, discrete SGs—preferably with small state and action spaces? I'm hoping to use such examples as benchmarks, but couldn't find much in the literature. One example I can think of is a [pursuit-evasion game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit-evasion) on a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the domains in the [International Probabilistic Planning Competition](https://ipc2018-probabilistic.bitbucket.io/), such as the *Wildlife Preserve* benchmark, fit quite well the constraints you have given. Note that the problems are modeled with a high-level declarative language, [RDDL](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~ssanner/Papers/RDDL_Tutorial.pdf). This means that you can define problems as big or as small as your heart desires with relative ease, since you can parametrize state description in terms of functions describing properties of an arbitrary number of objects.

There's also a [quite useful](https://github.com/thiagopbueno/rddlgym) project that allows to instance OpenAI `gym` environments from the declarative description of the environment, states and actions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at the two papers listed under Wildlife Preserve in the page you linked to, but it seems neither is a multi-state game?

Comment: From the definition of the instance (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/miquelramirez/67d35b824c01e2919241c774b1dcf737), file `wildlife-preserve_inst_mdp__01.rddl`), and the definition of the state variables (see section `state-fluents` in the file `wildlife-preserve_01_mdp.rddl` posted in the gist above) the smallest instance in the suite has 2^4 x 4 x 4 x 2 = 512 states. 

I recommend you too to play around with the `rddlgym` tool I linked in my answer, will make easier to come to grips with the syntax of RDDL.